# ljspeech Hugging Face examples not working

Tags: huggingface-transformers, fairseq

When trying to run the ljspeech [example](https://huggingface.co/facebook/fastspeech2-en-ljspeech), I get the following error, even when the model is moved to the only GPU in the system. I am using Cuda 11.7, Pytorch 1.13.1, and Fairseq 0.12.2.

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)
```

The code used:

```
from fairseq.checkpoint_utils import load_model_ensemble_and_task_from_hf_hub
from fairseq.models.text_to_speech.hub_interface import TTSHubInterface
import IPython.display as ipd
import torch


models, cfg, task = load_model_ensemble_and_task_from_hf_hub(
    "facebook/fastspeech2-en-ljspeech",
    arg_overrides={"vocoder": "hifigan", "fp16": False}
)
model = models[0].to(torch.device('cuda'))
models[0] = model
TTSHubInterface.update_cfg_with_data_cfg(cfg, task.data_cfg)
generator = task.build_generator(models, cfg)

text = "Hello, this is a test run."

sample = TTSHubInterface.get_model_input(task, text)
wav, rate = TTSHubInterface.get_prediction(task, model, generator, sample)

ipd.Audio(wav, rate=rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened when you run the code on a machine with GPU. Maybe there're some settings that auto-use the GPU when it's available.
I managed to run it on Google Colab (no GPU).

```
model = models[0]
TTSHubInterface.update_cfg_with_data_cfg(cfg, task.data_cfg)
generator = task.build_generator([model], cfg)
```